# Get the operating system in maxima

Tags: maxima

Is it possible to get the operating system in maxima? I have some code that needs the unix `/` or windows `\` for path names. How can I find out which operating system the code is running in?

To give some context, I have the following code:

```
windows: false$
divider: "/"$
if (windows) then divider: "\\"$
initfile: concat(maxima_userdir, divider, "maxima-init.mac");
load(operatingsystem)$
dir: getcurrentdirectory();
if (substring(dir, slength(dir)) # divider) then dir: concat(dir, divider)$
repo: concat(dir, "$$$.mac")$
live: concat(dir, "live_packages", divider, "$$$.mac")$
with_stdout(initfile, printf(true, ""))$
with_stdout(initfile, printf(true, concat("file_search_maxima: append (file_search_maxima, [
    ~s,
    ~s 
]);"), repo, live))$
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the output of `build_info`, specifically the field `host` (i.e. `foo@host` where `foo : build_info()`). See `? build_info` for more information.

On my (Linux) system I get: `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` I think on MS Windows you'll get a string containing `windows` or at least `win` or maybe `win32`.

There may be other ways to figure out the system type so let me know if that doesn't work for you. Also it is possible that there is a global variable floating around which tells the path separator; I would have to look for that.

Comment: For windows 10, I got `x86_64-w64-mingw32`. An apple, I got: `x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0` Maybe I can search for `w32` in the string to check if it is windows? Or maybe not `darwin` and not `linux`.

Comment: OK, that might work. But at some point it might become easier to work with pathname functions in Lisp rather than trying to accomplish the same thing via a more roundabout method in Maxima. I can help with the Lisp code if you decide to go down that road.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not adverse to writing a little bit of Lisp code, another approach is to use the file and directory functions in Common Lisp, which are more extensive than in Maxima. See [the section on filenames](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/c_filena.htm) in the Common Lisp Hyperspec. I think maybe MERGE-PATHNAMES and/or MAKE-PATHNAME might be relevant.